# Where can I obtain the raw atmospheric data that weather forecast images are based on?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, atmosphere-modelling, gfs

There is a lot of weather forecast data available online, such as this one
https://www.wetter3.de/animation_dt.html

But as a student, where do I get according raw GFS data instead of images to do my own (poor) data analysis?
To give an example: Is raw 500 hPa geopotential height data (see link above) available as a public downloadable file in some specific format or is this paid stuff just for professional organizations?

I found a lot of data here, but I'm not sure if this is the right entry point.
https://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/products/gfs/

Comment: Perhaps look here: https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/weather-climate-models/global-forecast

Comment: @MichaelW https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/21183/want-to-download-gfs-0-25-data-from-amazon-web-services

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch GFS from NCEP servers directly. It is documented here:
https://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/products/gfs/

For example, if you want today's 06 UTC run in 0.25-degree resolution, you would go [here](https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.20240113/06/atmos/) and look for the files named `gfs.t06z.pgrb2.0p25.f*`

You will get the files in the usual GRIB format. If you are unfamiliar with this format a good starting point would be to look at ecCodes from ECMWF ([github.com/ecmwf/eccodes](https://github.com/ecmwf/eccodes)).
If speed or easier access to the data, is important to you I would encourage you to have a look at gribscan ([github.com/gribscan/gribscan](https://github.com/gribscan/gribscan))

Comment: (Other options for decoding include xarray with cfgrib in Python, GrADS, or gempak)